# How to do the page curl like in storybook app in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, page-curl

I am working on a storybook app, i want to do the page curl like in the following video.

[Demo Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kA51BDHKTyc&feature=youtu.be)

Can anyone tell me how to do exactly like this.

**Update:**

I want this page curling to support iOS 4.3+. UIPageViewController will work only on iOS 6.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider `UIPageViewController`. It is quite useful in creating apps which use page curling animations. Here is the [documentations link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the UIView's animation effect for this. I guess this should help you

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Curl" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:contentView cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

where the contentView is the view where you are applying the animation. By varying the duration and animation curve you can modify your animation effect.

Comment: @croyneaus4u Thanks for your sample project , the page curling you've shown in this project is not exactly like in the video.Can you do like that video

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing it:

1. The hard way, implement everything yourself (from scratch, with layers and masks and transforms and gradients) and a lot of headache.
2. the Easy way, read the documentation for `UIPageViewController` as suggested by @Zen. Its very useful and gives you the exact animation that you want (as shown in video). Or, using some third party code.

If you dont't have time constraint, then I will say, go the first way. You will learn a lot.

Cheers, have fun :)

**EDIT**

Here is the link to a sample app:

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/x4qo2igrzvnkj16/CurlAnimationProject.zip

check it and tell me what you think.

Comment: I want this page curling to support iOS 4.3+. UIPageViewController will work only on iOS 6. so i choose the first way but i don't know how to do it. do you have any tutorial for this  or can you assist me in doing this

Comment: Ya it should support iOS 4.3 :-(

Comment: In the above sample I am transforming the superview 90 degree and the the subview -90 degree, and perform a pageCurlUp and pageCurlDown animation (as i have shown in the sample app). Since the superview has been rotated 90 degree the animation following a curlUp or curlDown looks as if its happening curlLeft and curlRight respectively.

Comment: @croyneaus4u did it well enough in the demo app with handling `UISwipegestureRecognizer` and transforming `contentView` etc. @surendher you can have a look at it to get an idea of what you're going to do. For supporting iOS<5, you'll have to do the core-graphics thing yourself.

Comment: `transitionWithVeiw` and `transform` are both available from iOS 4.0

Answer (score 0):

```
SettingViewController *svc = [[SettingViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SettingViewController" bundle:nil];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned several time in the answers the UIPageViewController ([apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html)) is the thing you should be looking at.

The implementation is fairly straightforward, the controller uses 2 delegates

- **datasource** : controlling the content to display (your pages) through 2 main methods
- **delegate** : controlling its behaviour

It implements the swipe gesture for scrolling from page to page and can feature a page control at the bottom of your view.

For transitioning from page to page, you can either set a scroll animation (nice for photo / portfolios type) or the page curl you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can make page curl/flip effect by

**For landscape mode:**

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Curl" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:contentView cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

---

**For portrait mode:**

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Curl" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlLeft forView:contentView cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```