# Segue Animation Only without switching viewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, swipe-gesture

I have a viewController with a TableView on it, and have Swipe Gesture Recognisers for left and right swipe to go to next and previous Detail record.

What I would like to do is use the left/Right Animation that segue uses, without actually doing a segue. I cant seem to find a way to do this, and I'm afraid if I "Segue to Self" I'll create multiple instances of the ViewController (Which I do not need).

They can swipe left a maximum of 100 times as I only allow them to see the last 100 rows, if that matters.

Does anyone know of a way to use the animation of Segue without the actual Segue part?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Trick is knowing what the Animations are called :-)
Once I found the keyword "Page Curl", a whole slew of options presented themselves :-)

[How to do the page curl like in storybook app in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392753/how-to-do-the-page-curl-like-in-storybook-app-in-ipad)

5 lines of code later, up and running!